# How to rewrite compiler.plugin('done'...) with the new Webpack API?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

This

```
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
compiler.plugin('done', function(stat) {
});
```

Warns:

> (node:63533) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead

I know I got to get it to look something like this:

```
compiler.hooks.done.tapAsync('webpack', function(stat) {})
```

Of course that doesn't work. Haven't found the docs either.

Comment: Yeah, it is correct. What does not work? I have a plugin for done too, and works perfectly fine. `webpackCompiler.hooks.done.tap('BuildStatsPlugin', something...);`

Comment: Be aware that, tapAsync and tap have different effects, so choose wisely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
webpackCompiler.hooks.done.tap('BuildStatsPlugin', (stats) => {
  ....
});
```

Although, according to the source code, it is described as an [AsyncHook](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/Compiler.js#L54), i have this working on a production code, and works as expected.

Comment: Note to myself: "BuildStatsPlugin" is a the name of the plugin we are developing ... so it can be any string.